# Join two select queries horizontally in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have following two queries:

Query #1:

```
(SELECT 
    pl.c_project_Id, pl.c_projectphase_Id, pl.c_projecttask_Id, pl.m_product_Id,
    pj.name as projectname, ph.name as phasename, pt.name as taskname, pd.name as prodname,
    round(pl.plannedqty, 2) as planqty, round(pl.plannedprice, 2) as planrate,
    round(pl.plannedamt, 2) as planamt

FROM adempiere.c_projectline pl
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_project pj ON pl.c_project_id = pj.c_project_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_projectphase ph ON pl.c_projectphase_id = ph.c_projectphase_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_projecttask pt ON pl.c_projecttask_id = pt.c_projecttask_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.m_product pd ON pl.m_product_id = pd.m_product_id
WHERE pl.c_project_id = 1000001 AND pl.ad_client_id = 1000000
ORDER BY ph.c_projectphase_id, pt.c_projecttask_id)
```

Output is: 11 columns and 16 rows

Query #2:

```
(SELECT
    fa.c_project_id, fa.c_projectphase_id, fa.c_projecttask_id, fa.m_product_id,
    pj.name as costprojectname, ph.name as costphasename, pt.name as costtaskname,
    pd.name as costprodname,
    abs(fa.qty) as costqty, round((fa.amtacctdr/fa.qty), 2) as costrate,
    round(sum(fa.amtacctdr), 0) as costamt

FROM adempiere.fact_acct fa
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_project pj ON fa.c_project_id = pj.c_project_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_projectphase ph ON fa.c_projectphase_id = ph.c_projectphase_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.c_projecttask pt ON fa.c_projecttask_id = pt.c_projecttask_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.m_product pd ON fa.m_product_id = pd.m_product_id
WHERE  fa.c_project_id = 1000001 AND (fa.gl_category_id = 1000006 OR fa.gl_category_id = 1000005)
AND fa.qty > 0 AND fa.c_project_id is not null
GROUP BY fa.m_product_id, fa.c_project_id, fa.c_projectphase_id, fa.c_projecttask_id,
        fa.qty, fa.amtacctdr,
        pj.name, ph.name, pt.name, pd.name)
```

Output is: 11 columns and 6 rows

I want to join these queries horizontally, display all columns but rows should not duplicate. As when I apply union to join them the result shows duplicate rows. How can I cope with this issue?

Comment: How do you match the rows between the queries?

Answer (score 29):

You should be able to join queries like this:

```
select * from
  (
   <your first query here>
  ) tbl1
  join (
    <your second query here>
  ) tbl2
  on tbl1.c_project_Id = tbl2.c_project_Id
 and tbl1.c_projectphase_Id = tbl2.c_projectphase_Id -- you might add or
 and tbl1.c_projecttask_Id  = tbl2.c_projecttask_Id  -- remove join criteria 
 and tbl1.m_product_Id = tbl2.m_product_Id           -- here
```

Comment: alzaimar Thank you for reply. I apply your solution but it shows all columns and only 6 rows where match all criteria. But I need all 16 rows from the 1st query and from 2nd query values of columns(costqty, costrate, aostamt) where criteria match otherwise show zero. What should i do?

Comment: Use a 'full join' instead. The reason that only 6 rows are shown is most likel because only 6 rows share the same 'join' criteria.

So add a 'full ' before the 'join' keyword and examine the results.

Comment: Yes "FULL JOIN" is working and I am getting my results very accurately. A really Big Thanks to you for help.

Comment: I didn't get the query until I took a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653828/joining-2-select-queries-on-2-different-tables-in-postgresql